# there is a limitation of client socket connection

Tags: tcp, windows-xp, client

I made a tcp/ip echo server by using kqueue on a unix(OSX) machine.It desinged to open 100 tcp/ip ports and accept 4000 clients per port.I made about 230,000 connections by using 15 another machines. ( 4000 conn per single process, and 4 process per box)

It seems that the server could accept more than that but the problem was the client side.There is a limitation to make much connections. Such as Windows XP - 3000, Windows7 & Unix - 16384 ..

Is the limitation right ? did I wrong ? I want to make as much connections as I can on a single client, such as 500,000 / Machine.

How could I overcome ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure multiple IPv4 address on the client machine. Process that runs on client should receive source IP address as parameter, and bind connect socket to it. So with 10 IP addresses you can easily reach 400000 connections.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make as much connections as I can on a single client, such as 500,000 / Machine.

You can't. A TCP connection is identified by the tuple {protocol, source address, source port, target address, target port}. Four of these five elements are fixed. The remaining element, source port, can only have 65535 distinct values at the most, as a port number has 16 bits and cannot be zero.

So your expectation of 500,000 connnections to the same client is over-optimistic by a factor of about 10.